# How to match braces or brackets?

Tags: regular-expression, search, delimiter-matching

Suppose I want to search for things like

`\todo{English sentence}`

Then the regex

`\\todo{\_.\{-}}`

works (I don't know why. I copied it from somewhere long time ago (embarrassed)).

But suppose I want to match things like

`\todo{anything whatsoever}`

Then the above regex is no good.

For example, if I have

`\todo{The problem is caused because of {another} pair of braces inside}`

The previous regex just matches

`\todo{The problem is caused because of {another}`

What is the correct regex, and if possible, can someone break it down a little bit? Things like `\_.\{-}` already seem to make no sense!

Big thanks.

Comment: Regexes aren't meant to match recursive patterns. There exists hacks that do so, but in the end they are still hacks that recursively inject (up to a point before the slow down is too important) ways to workaround embedded pairs of brackets. You'll have better luck if you select up to the `{` then, jump to `}` with `%` -- as long as you can still apply the action you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the help pages in Vim:

```
\{-}    matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible
*       Matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible.
```

In my small test case replacing the former with the latter matched your example string. That is:

```
\\todo{\_.*}
```

Comment: It was working for me at first. But after the text became more complicated, a problem has appeared. The regex you have suggested is also matching `\\todo{stuff} as long as there is a closing brace}`

Answer (score 1):

As @LucHermite already mentioned [in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/how-to-match-braces-or-brackets#comment28766_16774), regular expressions are not meant for recursive patterns. The solution by @Vitor does not work, as was already confirmed [in the comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/how-to-match-braces-or-brackets#comment28767_16777), because it will match beyond the last `}` of the `\todo` command if possible.

Since you did not write anything about what your end goal is, it is difficult to give further concrete tips here. But I would think that you could solve your initial problem e.g. with something like this:

1. Search for `\\todo`
2. Do `vf{` to select up until the first `{`
3. Do `%` to increase the selection up until the closing `}`

If you need some sort of repeated action, you can combine these things with a macro, e.g. `qa/\\todo<cr>vf{% ... q` where `...` is the action you want to perform. Then you can run the macro with `@a` to repeat.